# Using "Shrink to One Page" with VBA

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I have found a great feature called `"Shrink to One Page"` in Microsoft Word. I want to call this feature via a macro on `Document Open` event.

https://lextechreview.com/microsoft-word-tips-hidden-feature-shrink-one-page/

I have found these links but can't find exactly what I want.

Eg:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.shrink

```
If Selection.Type = wdSelectionNormal Then 
 Selection.Shrink 
Else 
 MsgBox "You need to select some text." 
End If
```

But this only does the following --> This example collapses the selected text to the next smaller unit of text.

I need it to "Shrink to One Page"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the method name you want to use is `FitToPages`. It applies to the whole document and not just a single page as the Quick Access Toolbar label implies.

An example usage of the command would be: `ActiveDocument.FitToPages`

Comment: Unfortunately that has different results then what I'm after.